# How to create a fixed vertical navigation?

Tags: html, css

Here's an example. http://rsvp-paris.com/ As you can see, their shipping methods are rotated and are on both ends of each side. This is what I did:

```
.vertical{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

However I'm using Foundation, so things get a little wacky when I scale the screen down. I just want a simple vertical text in one line, that is fixed in the middle right side of the screen.

[image: Like This]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use combined `transform` values of `rotate()` + `translate()` for it.

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/objzajar/)**

```css
.vertical {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%, 0);
  transform-origin: top right;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
.vertical li:first-child {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="vertical">
  <li>Item One</li>
  <li>Item Two</li>
  <li>Item Three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're amazing. Thanks a lot for the help!